# Giving local account access to domain fileshare

Tags: domain, file-permissions

I have a user who needed to create scheduled tasks that will convert files on a server to a different filetype (working with autocad type files). He's on a standard user account which doesn't give him sufficient rights to create the scheduled tasks. After a lot of troubleshooting and testing we found the easiest and most secure way to allow him to finish his tasks is to create a local admin account for him and then map the network drive he needs access to using his domain credentials. It has been working somewhat fine expect about every other day the task won't run and when he logs into the local account he sees that the network drive has been disconnected. 
We're thinking of giving giving his local admin account access to the file share he required. Is there a way to give only his specific local account read/write access to a fileshare on our server without creating a security risk/opening the share to anyone? Or are there any other possible options we could explore?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming there's a reason you can't just add his domain account to the machine's local administrators group.  If not, that would be the easiest way.)

Back in the workgroup days, you would grant share permissions to an identical username with the same password. You can still do this if you create a local user on the server with the same username, and give them the same password as the user's local account.  I've done this with a local account to allow a domain account access to a local share when there's no trust between the domains.

Comment: Thank you, adding him to local admins should do the trick. I should've thought of that before.